# Using default prefix on Laravel for group routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I was wondering: Could I put some sort of default paramenter(s) for a group of routes.
(e.g.) I have a web service. This will use the same type of authentication AWS uses. Nothing new, so far... No matter the requisition, I will need to have this structure:

```
myapp.com/v1/{hashed_value}/{timestamp}/{parameters}
```

Where:

**v1** -> Stands for versioning (o rly?!)
**hashed_value** -> Is a hash for all informations I'm sending on get request (URL itself).
timestamp -> Something to verify if someone hasn't hold it up to crack it and send it back. Expiration time.
**parameters** -> We all need them, don't we? Maybe (probably will) more them one.

Well, in that case, there's a dummy way of doing it, that consists in putting this 3 variables in all (!!) my routes. But thats not what I want! I want the "Laravel way" of doing it!
If I was able, I don't know, to put this as a prefix (those being variables) for a group of routes, in that case all of them, "that would be great". I don't know if there's a way of doing it... there is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is absolutely possible.  I took part of my `routes` files out, and changed some names to make it clear what it does.  My suggestion is to put the parameters first, and then put the unknowns (such as hash and timestamp) at the end.

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function()
{
    //the routes for all API calls
    Route::group(array('prefix' => '/v1'), function()
    {
        //for version 1
        Route::group(array('prefix' => '/parameter_type_1', 'before' => 'loggedin'), function()
        {
            //for parameter_type_1 requests
            Route::get('/getThing/{hash}/{timestamp}', 'APIController@getThing');

        Route::group(array('prefix' => '/parameter_type_2', 'before' => 'loggedin'), function()
        {
            //for parameter_type_2 requests
            Route::get('/getNewThing/{hash}/{timestamp}',  'APIController@getNewThing');
        });
    });

});
```

Some documentation links for you:

- Laravel prefix groups: http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-prefixing
- Variable prefix extension (if you need to have the hash/timestamp first): https://github.com/jasonlewis/enhanced-router

Comment: Nice and solid answer. Thanks for the link, btw! =D